# $A$ is the adjacency matrix for cubic graph $G$ of order $n$. Prove the number of length-4 cycles is $(tr (A^4) - 15 n)/8$

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone give me a hint for this question, I know most of the number means but I just do not know what does the '$-15n$' in the formula mean.

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix for $G$ a simple cubic graph of order $n$. Prove that the number of cycles in $G$ of length 4 is given by

$$(tr(A^4)-15 n)/8$$

Comment: Note that $A^2$ will have 3 on the diagonal, and up to six 1s in each row. Thus $A^4=(A^2)^2$ might have 15 on the diagonal, and that 15 has nothing to do with 4-cycles, it comes from $G$ being cubic.

Comment: Where did the question arise?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MO is not for getting help with assigned exercises (if this is what this is)

Comment: $tr A^4$ counts closed walks of the form $abcda$. Since the starting point $a$ can be anywhere on the cycle you are overcounting by a factor of $4$. You also have two directions of travel so you also need to divide by two. Now $(tr A^4)/8$ is not quite correct since you are including degenerate walks. You need to subtract them before dividing by $8$. There are $3n$ degenerate walks of the form $ababa$ ($n$ ways of choosing $a$ and $3$ for the neighbor $b$ because the graph is cubic). There are also $12n$ walks of the form $abaca$ (and cyclic permutations)...

Comment: ...you can count them by choosing the articulation vertex ($n$ ways), choosing the two edges involved ($3$ ways) and finally how you want to travel ($1+1+2$ ways, since starting from $b$ or $c$ you have no choice, but starting from $a$ you have two choices for your first step).